# About three vector lines

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

**Question:**

> Given two intersecting lines and the direction cosines of a third line, find the third line such that it intersects the other two lines.
>
> It is given that $L_3$ intersects both the lines in *exactly two distinct points*.

State the method by which you'll proceed.

**My attempt:**

I let the given lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect at point $P$. Now, obviously, these lines form a plane $A$ since they are intersecting lines.

For a third line to intersect both these two lines, it must also be coplanar with both of them i.e. line $L_3$ must lie in the plane $A$.

Thus, my answer is that the question has:

1. **no solution:** if given direction cosines for $L_3$ are NOT parallel to the plane.
2. **infinite solutions:** if given direction cosines for $L_3$ are parallel to the plane (since we may vary the perpendicular distance of $L_3$ from $P$ while maintaining the question's condition).

---

Is my answer correct? If not, then why?

Comment: Are you working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar 3D space (so I believe $R^3$)

Comment: It is also possible that $P$ is on the third line $L_3$, while $L_3$ does not need to be in the plane

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar You're right, I will clarify it in the question. It is given that $L_3$ intersects both the lines in two points. Side note: In your case there is no point of asking this question since then $L_3$ is known automatically (we know its direction cosines and also the point through which it passes) :P

Comment: Then your answer is correct, $L_3$ must lie in the plane of $L_1$ and $L_2$ not parallel with one of these lines.

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar Thanks!